retrieve data from mongodb with express Js
i have to run the npm command npm install express mongoose cors
then i am running database called studentsRecords with collection student having the following data
db.students.insertMany({id:1},{name:'John'},{id:2,name:'Doe'});
i want to display those data to my web browser with express only as i did on the code bellow , but it display errors (i.e does not fetch any of the given data from database) , how to fix the code so it can work properly?
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// Schema and model
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const DataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});
const Data = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);

// Route to fetch data by name and id
app.get('/data/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.params;

    const data = await Data.find({ name: name }, { _id: 0, name: 1 });
    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send('Data not found');
    }
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});


What are the errors?

Your insertMany syntax to add data into students collection doesn't look correct.

Are you sure you are reading from the students collection in your ExpressJS app?

Version 2 of the code: A new route path for all is added.
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

// Schema and model
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const DataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});
const Data = mongoose.model('student', DataSchema);

// Route to fetch all
// IMPORTANT : keep this route path always on top of the other route path '/data/:name'
// else retrieval will fail.
app.get('/data/all', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await Data.find({}, { _id: 0, name: 1 });

    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send('Data not found');
    }
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Route to fetch data by name and id
app.get('/data/:name', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.params;

    const data = await Data.find({ name: name }, { _id: 0, name: 1 });

    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send('Data not found');
    }
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});


how can i use the same logic to insert , update  and delete?

The idea remains the same. At present it works for view function. At present there is a route handler for view. And this route handler has a mongoose model to do the database job. That is all in a nutshell. Now let us say for insert, there should be another route handler, and inside that handler there should be mongoose model operation. That is all. Start writing something in these lines, and then try. There will be issues or errors, please post it in the comments. Shall help.

Hi, Has my previous comment helped you ? Is there anything more to do for this ?

Hi, Have you been able to develop the other routes ?

nah , i tried but it didn't work ... where can i share the code? so you can review them for improvement

No issues. Appreciate your attempt. If you have a test github repository, please upload it over there and share the repo path. If not, i shall provide one, you can upload it.

if so , let me dive into  github , then i will share the repo path here on comments

In principle your code is well-set.
I tried the same, and it resulted in the desired output below. The subsequent post explains a few corrections to be applied to make your code completely working. Please try it and for clarifications if any required from me, please post your comments.
Testing in Browser:
Request URL : http://localhost:3000/data/John

Response : 
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  }
]

Enclosing a few observations and comments:
point 1:
“…then i am running database called studentsRecords with collection student having the following data
db.students.insertMany({id:1},{name:'John'},{id:2,name:'Doe'});...”
observations & comments:
As per the above note,
database name : studentsRecords
collection name : students // Please note it is not just student alone, s is also suffixed.

Now we shall create the documents as below:
The prior requirements are the db should be pointing to the database studentsRecords and the insertMany statement should refer to the collection students. The respective codes are given below.
// start mongo shell
command prompt>mongosh

// check the list of available databases 
mongosh prompt>show dbs

// switch to the database studentsRecords
mongosh prompt>use studentsRecords

// create the documents, please note there should be a set of curly braces to separate each document.
mongosh prompt>db.students.insertMany({id:1,name:'John'},{id:2,name:'Doe'});

// check and verify the documents are created as desired
mongosh prompt>db.students.find();
[
  { _id: ObjectId('6672396e2241632216628d55'), id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { _id: ObjectId('6672396e2241632216628d56'), id: 2, name: 'Doe' }
]

point 2:
// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
comments:
The database referenced in the connection string is to be corrected as per the discussions we have done in point 1. Therefore the corrected statement would be as below. Please note that the two keys useNewUrlParser and useUnifiedTopology passed into the options object are now deprecated therefore it is now omitted.
…
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/studentsRecords);
…

point 3:
…
const Data = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
…
comments:
The collection name passed into the method model needs to be changed from Data to student, this is again as per the discussion we have done in point 1. Please also note that it must be a singular name, therefore it is student not students. Mongoose will automatically look for its plural name. The corrected code is given below:
const Data = mongoose.model(student, DataSchema);

point 4:
// Route to fetch data by name and id
app.get('/data/’, async (req, res) => {
comments:
The route path /data/ should be prefixed with a route parameter as well. This is to get the respective value specified in the request URL.  The corrected code is given below.
…
app.get('/data/:name’, async (req, res) => {...

The full listing of corrected code:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/studentsRecords');

// Schema and model
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const DataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});

const Data = mongoose.model('student', DataSchema);

// Route to fetch data by name and id
app.get('/data/:name', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.params;

    const data = await Data.find({ name: name }, { _id: 0, name: 1 });
    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send('Data not found');
    }
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});


it shows an error    Data not found

Please share the request URL you have tried, i mean like this http://localhost:3000/data/John. Along with it, please share the output of this step or command mongosh prompt>db.students.find();

Hi, Is the issue still persisting.

it works now localhost:3000/data/John. , then assume i want to query all the names and not only single name like John , something like this localhost:3000/data (display all data )

Thank you. The confirmation of yours would encourage others as well to use this content.

"...then assume i want to query all..." : Have added a new route for all data, please see the answer updated.

it doesn't work ,

Yes, it had missed, Sorry, now added. Please look at the second answer. The first answer is not getting amended.
